# Google Chrome Lighthouse performance score of 0

Tags: performance, lighthouse

In Google Chrome Lighthouse my Best practices score is 75 and SEO score is 90 but my Performance score is 0.

I keep getting notifications that my "First Meaningful Paint" takes up to 43 seconds!

I've been reading [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/prpl-pattern/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/first-meaningful-paint).
And tried to deconstruct what is causing this. I've done almost everything that is recommended by the report and I can think of to increase performance:

- minify JS/CSS
- bundle JS
- lazy load images
- exclude 3rd party social scripts
- gzip the page
- reduce render blocking CSS/JS

I run the test in an anonymous browsing session with no extensions active. But still my performance is 0 in this report!

The page I'm testing is [here](https://www.toptrouwen.nl/bedrijven/trouwlocaties).
What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

After analysing your page, here are the steps I would take.

1. Add a `rel=preload` attribute onto the font CSS links (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload)
2. Use next generation image formats, such as webp and jpeg-xr (You could try https://cloudinary.com/ if you don't want to roll your own server)
3. Inline above the fold CSS into the head and defer the loading of external CSS files (https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/)
4. Increase the CacheControl TTL for images resources to 30 days (currently you have 7 days) (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)

You score and perceived page load speed will be dramatically increased by doing so.